# Worker Role with Service Bus Queue - multiple queues

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azureservicebus

I need to create a worker role to process messages from multiple queues. I realized that there's a cloud project Worker Role with Service Bus Queue. Can I create multiple Queue Clients using this one or should I separate in N Worker Roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no restriction on how many Queues you can process from a single Worker role, you can create several QueueClients and then kick off Receive calls in parallel or register with OnMessage.

From an application perspective you need to think about isolation and scaling in that if you have queues with different types of workloads or different priorities then having different processing backends can provide more flexibility.

Comment: Right now I had created more than one QueueClient and each one is pumping from one queue. I'll test, and if everything works fine, I'll mark your answer as response. Thanks!

Comment: After OnMessage the brokeredmessage will be removed from queue automatically?

Comment: By default yes, when the function completes the message is removed. You can use OnMessageOptions to change that behavior if needed.